# Периодически перестает работать FTP

Tags: файлы, сервер, ftp

Не знаю почему и как но частенько у меня перестает работать фтп, ПРИЧЕМ на всех фтп-клиентах сразу, качал новые, переустанавливал - не помогает, перезагрузка компьютера тоже, через некоторое время само подключает.. Ничего не понимаю
лог ошибок:

```
Ошибка: Соединение прервано после 20 секунд неактивности
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
Статус: Ожидание повтора...
Статус: Определение IP-адреса для ***
Статус: Соединяюсь с ***...
Ошибка: Соединение прервано после 20 секунд неактивности
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
Статус: Ожидание повтора...
Статус: Определение IP-адреса для ***
Статус: Соединяюсь с ***...
Ошибка: Соединение прервано после 20 секунд неактивности
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
```

и так всё вемя

приходится пользоваться онлайн клиентом

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема с разрешением. Обычно когда идет подключение к серверу, всплывает окошко где Windows требует согласие, без которого подключение не проходит. Возможно у тебя стоит автоматический запрет. Насколько я знаю это Брандмауэр Windows надо открыть и покопаться.

Comment: Но большую часть времени всё норм, никакого окошка не выскакивало